# Web scraping with Hippo CMS

Tags: web-scraping, hippocms

I am looking for web scraping plugins like Web Scraper and MyCurator which can be integrated with Hippo CMS.I need the same functionality which is provided by the above mentioned plugins but with Hippo.Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate anything you want in Hippo. Not sure what your usecase is, but I would run a scraper as an independent service and have it communicate with Hippo through rest. You can also write a Daemon service There is no default functionality or current plugin (known to me) that provides this.